# rails 5 how to pass models value to dashboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, adminlte

I am created an app that included adminlte dashboard. and my dashboard contain so many value getting by JQuery file. I want to pass module value to dashboard.
Fox ex: number of users shows in dashboard and getting from user model( this user list must be getting from User model)

can anybody help me how to do this?

Any help, must appreciated very much

Answer (score 0):

I hope there is no way to pass a value from client side scripting(JS) to Server Side without any proper request.

However, this can be done via AJAX request. You can just pass your module value to rails controller and through that can display in your dashboard as rails variable.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Could you like to refer me to how to do that properly any reference? I don't know AJAX stuff so

Comment: The below sample code might be helpful for making an ajax request to rails controller.


`$(function() {

  $("#submit_button").on("click", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "your_controller_url",
      data: "your_form_data"
      success: function(result) {
        // Append the result to a table or list, $("list").append(result)
      },
    });
  });
});`